# Accessing react context without using contextType or set a default context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to access nearest context from provider without explicitly declaring contextType in a component using `this.context`?

OR is there a way to set default context so when i say `this.context` I would get that context value?

Comment: What about creating base class (which will inherit with `Component` of course) and the components will inherit for it?

Comment: but then i would have to explicitly make an HOC for all those components to supply contextType, i was kind of hoping to get a shortcut out of that which i am not sure if possible.

Comment: Sure? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-te4pm6.

Comment: If it answer the question, I'll put it as an answer..

Comment: @MoshFeu the link is dead :/

Comment: Sorry, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-base-component-context?file=Hello.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you yourself mentioned in comments HOC is actually a good idea. 
You can write pure reusable components and wrap them with the same function. For exmaple, something like this should do the trick.

P.s. no, there is no easy way to get the closest context. Also, doing so is basically inviting bugs if at some point you will add additional contexts (Redux, i18n, etc.)

```
const withContext = (Context, propName) => (Component) => (props) => (
  <Context.Consumer>
    {(value) => (React.createElement(Component, { ...props, [propName]: value }))}
  </Context.Consumer>
);

const withThemeContext = withContext(ThemeContext, 'theme');

// MyComponent will have this.props.theme
const MyComponent = withThemeContext(MyPureComponent);
```